# Does any transformation of a random variable result in a valid PDF?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have a random variable $X$ with PDF $f_X(x)=\frac{e^{-x}}{(1+e^{-x})^2}, \  x\in(-\infty,\infty)$. When I apply the transformation $Y=X^2$, I obtain Y with PDF $f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}\left(\frac{e^{\sqrt{y}}}{(1+e^{\sqrt{y}})^2}+\frac{e^{-\sqrt{y}}}{(1+e^{-\sqrt{y}})^2}\right) \ y\in[0,\infty)$. I checked that this integrates to one, however what strikes me as strange is that the PDF is undefined at zero. What does this mean? Is this a valid PDF? Do all transformations result in valid PDFs given that the starting PDF was valid?

Comment: I am not a theorist, so others can perhaps comment more precisely.  My understanding is that it is quite OK for the PDF to have infinite values, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1761166/infinite-probability-density) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/689437/is-it-valid-for-a-probability-density-function-take-the-value-infty-somewhere) for examples.  In my mind, the CDF is the more "fundamental" object and the PDF is merely its derivative, if the derivative exists.

Comment: Further, if the PDF is continuous and finite at $x_0$, then $P( [x_0 - \delta, x_0 + \delta] ) \to 2 f(x_0) \delta$, i.e. the prob shrinks linearly with $\delta$.  Any time it shrinks slower than linearly, it will have infinite PDF, I think.  I haven't checked your math, but I am curious if $P(Y \le \delta)$ in your case shrinks as $\propto \sqrt{\delta}$...